# Two times request on same aspx.cs page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page whose name is getlogo1.aspx on its code behind I am getting two times page request when hitting URL  `localhost:53939/getlogo1.aspx?logoID=waThGNWCd8Q=` during debugging in VS 2013.

Firstly in `Global.asax` `Application_AuthenticateRequest()` then on `Page_Load()` whose response is  "image/png" and the response image successfully displayed on the web browser.

Secondly after image is displayed then again `Application_AuthenticateRequest()` and `Page_Load()` but browser tab does not reloaded.

I am unable to find why this is again going to same code second time.